# Storing Twitch Oauth Tokens in Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, oauth, google-cloud-firestore, token

I'm creating a web app in which user's can link their Twitch account. I'm using Firestore as my database. Is there a secure way to store the user's Twitch Oauth token in Firestore? If not, what is the proper way to store a token?

I don't want to create a new token each time they log in, as this requires them to go through the auth process again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a secure way to store the user's Twitch Oauth token in Firestore?

Yes there is, using [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started). So you can store the Twitch Oauth token in your Firestore database and write the corresponding security rules so only authorized users can read/write it.

Comment: Yes, I know also that all Firestore data is encrypted. I was just wondering since admins can see the database in plain text, if that is considered OK by industry standards.

Comment: If you need your token to be in another format than this, then you should encrypt it, right?